# subclass str, and make new method with same effect as +=

Tags: python, string, subclass, immutability, built-in

I'm trying to subclass `str` - not for anything important, just an experiment to learn more about Python built-in types.  I've subclassed `str` this way (using `__new__` because `str` is immutable):

```
class MyString(str):
    def __new__(cls, value=''):
        return str.__new__(cls, value)
    def __radd__(self, value):  # what method should I use??
        return MyString(self + value)  # what goes here??
    def write(self, data):
        self.__radd__(data)
```

It initializes right, as far as I can tell. but I cant get it to modify itself in-place using the += operator.  I've tried overriding `__add__`, `__radd__`, `__iadd__` and a variety of other configurations. Using a `return` statement, ive managed to get it to return a new instance of the correct appended `MyString`, but not modify in place.  Success would look like:

```
b = MyString('g')
b.write('h')  # b should now be 'gh'
```

Any thoughts?

### UPDATE

To possibly add a reason why someone might want to do this, I followed the suggestion of creating the following mutable class that uses a plain string internally:

```
class StringInside(object):

    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self.data = data

    def write(self, data):
        self.data += data

    def read(self):
        return self.data
```

and tested with timeit:

```
timeit.timeit("arr+='1234567890'", setup="arr = ''", number=10000)
0.004415035247802734
timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890')", setup="from hard import StringInside; arr = StringInside()", number=10000)
0.0331270694732666
```

The difference increases rapidly at the `number` goes up - at 1 million interactions, `StringInside` took longer than I was willing to wait to return, while the pure `str` version returned in ~100ms.

### UPDATE 2

For posterity, I decided to write a cython class wrapping a C++ string to see if performance could be improved compared to one loosely based on Mike Müller's updated version below, and I managed to succeed.  I realize cython is "cheating" but I provide this just for fun.

python version:

```
class Mike(object):

    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self._data = []
        self._data.extend(data)

    def write(self, data):
        self._data.extend(data)

    def read(self, stop=None):
        return ''.join(self._data[0:stop])

    def pop(self, stop=None):
        if not stop:
            stop = len(self._data)
        try:
            return ''.join(self._data[0:stop])
        finally:
            self._data = self._data[stop:]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ''.join(self._data[key])
```

cython version:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef class CyString:
    cdef string buff
    cdef public int length

    def __cinit__(self, string data=''):
        self.length = len(data)
        self.buff = data

    def write(self, string new_data):
        self.length += len(new_data)
        self.buff += new_data

    def read(self, int length=0):
        if not length:
            length = self.length
        return self.buff.substr(0, length)  

    def pop(self, int length=0):
        if not length:
            length = self.length
        ans = self.buff.substr(0, length)
        self.buff.erase(0, length)
        return ans
```

performance:

writing

```
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890')", setup="from pyversion import Mike; arr = Mike()", number=1000000)
0.5992741584777832
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890')", setup="from cyversion import CyBuff; arr = CyBuff()", number=1000000)
0.17381906509399414
```

reading

```
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890'); arr.read(5)", setup="from pyversion import Mike; arr = Mike()", number=1000000)
1.1499049663543701
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890'); arr.read(5)", setup="from cyversion import CyBuff; arr = CyBuff()", number=1000000)
0.2894480228424072
```

popping

```
>>> # note I'm using 10e3 iterations - the python version wouldn't return otherwise
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890'); arr.pop(5)", setup="from pyversion import Mike; arr = Mike()", number=10000)
0.7390561103820801
>>> timeit.timeit("arr.write('1234567890'); arr.pop(5)", setup="from cyversion import CyBuff; arr = CyBuff()", number=10000)
0.01501607894897461
```

Comment: You can not modify strings in place, because they are immutable.  The only option is creating a new string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by subclassing an immutable class, the new class is by definition also immutable, hence your inability to change it in place. To get the behavior you want, you'd have to create a mutable class that maybe has a `str` as a property that you change.

Comment: yes, I'm aware, but if `i = 'ab'`, then `i += 'c'`, i will be 'abc'. Under the hood, it's a new string, sure, and this is the behavior I am trying to replicate - but use the `write` method to do so.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because strings don't do that with `__radd__`.  It just falls back to `i = i + 'c'`.

Comment: another way of stating the question is "how can i make the `write` method on `MyString` work the same way as += does on `str`: if i holds the value 'ab', then after `i.write('c')` i holds 'abc'.

Comment: Never ever ever subclass `str`. It's simply not useful. If you want to make your own string class, subclass just `object` or subclass an ABC from the collections module.

Comment: i made no claims of utility!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

This is an answer to the updated question.

You can use a list to hold data and only construct the string when reading it:

```
class StringInside(object):

    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self._data = []
        self._data.append(data)

    def write(self, data):
        self._data.append(data)

    def read(self):
        return ''.join(self._data)
```

### Performance

The performance of this class:

```
%%timeit arr = StringInside()
arr.write('1234567890')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 352 ns per loop
```

is much closer to that of the native `str`:

```
%%timeit str_arr = ''
str_arr+='1234567890'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 222 ns per loop
```

Compare with your version:

```
%%timeit arr = StringInsidePlusEqual()
arr.write('1234567890')
100000 loops, best of 3: 87 µs per loop
```

### Reason

The `my_string += another_string` way of building a string has been an anti-pattern performance wise for a long time. CPython has some optimizations for this case. Seems like CPython cannot detect that this pattern is used here. This likely because it a bit hidden inside a class.

Not all implementations have this optimization for various reasons. For example. PyPy, which in general is much faster than CPython, is considerably slower for this use case:

PyPy 2.6.0 (Python 2.7.9)

```
>>>> import timeit
>>>> timeit.timeit("arr+='1234567890'", setup="arr = ''", number=10000)
0.08312582969665527
```

CPython 2.7.11

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("arr+='1234567890'", setup="arr = ''", number=10000)
0.002151966094970703
```

### Slice-able version

This version supports slicing:

```
class StringInside(object):

    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self._data = []
        self._data.extend(data)

    def write(self, data):
        self._data.extend(data)

    def read(self, start=None, stop=None):
        return ''.join(self._data[start:stop])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ''.join(self._data[key])
```

You can slice the normal way:

```
>>> arr = StringInside('abcdefg')
>>> arr[2]
'c'
>>> arr[1:3]
'bc'
```

Now, `read()` also supports optional start and stop indices:

```
>>>  arr.read()
'abcdefg'
>>> arr.read(1, 3)
'bc'

>>> arr.read(1)
'bcdefg'
```

Comment: As posed, this does indeed answer the original problem quite nicely.  I'd been hoping to be able to pop off arbitrary length slices of the underlying string - giving it buffer-like qualities (yes, I know, i could just use `cStringIO`, but this was an exercise in builtin types). This approach makes that kind of convoluted. I'm happy to accept it as-is, but i wondered if you had any thoughts on this other requirement.

Comment: Added a version that supports slicing.

Comment: Hi Mike - I'm accepting it - I had worked on a similar approach myself, and it is pretty fast if you are just reading the slices, but slows down when you pop them out, not surprisingly.  Anyway, my conclusion is "don't do this with a string subclass, or try to use a banana to pound a hammer, even if it's fun" - Thanks for humoring me!

Comment: Very clever, kudos for the simple and elegant solution.

Comment: The `sliceable` suggestion was very useful. After that, I didn't have a need to subclass `str` anymore.